# how to use dictionary value as row index of pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
movies = [{'title':'kingsman','speakers':['JHON','KEVIN'...],'dialogue':['my name is jhon','hi..']},{....}]
```

I want to make a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
row_index sp   di
kingsman JHON 'my name is john'
kingsman KEVIN 'hi..'
```

I want possibly the row index to be the movie title.
I know how to create pandas dataframe with the speaker list and the dialogue list, but how can I use title as a row index?

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension for list of tuples and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
movies = [{'title':'kingsman','speakers':['JHON','KEVIN'],
                              'dialogue':['my name is jhon','hi..']}]

L = [(x['title'], y1, y2) for x in movies for y1, y2 in zip(x['speakers'],x['dialogue'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['title','speakers','dialogue'])
print (df)
      title speakers         dialogue
0  kingsman     JHON  my name is jhon
1  kingsman    KEVIN             hi..
```

**Performance**: with sample data, real shoud be different, but here list comprehension solution is very fast:

```
movies = [{'title':'kingsman','speakers':['JHON','KEVIN'],
                              'dialogue':['my name is jhon','hi..']}]

movies = movies * 10000

In [112]: %timeit pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(movie) for movie in movies])
6.15 s ± 263 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [113]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([(x['title'], y1, y2) for x in movies for y1, y2 in zip(x['speakers'],x['dialogue'])], columns=['title','speakers','dialogue'])
9.45 ms ± 97.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can thing of is by creating **a dataframe for each entry** in the list and **concatenate all dataframes**.

For your example would be:

```py
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(movie) for movie in movies])
```

If you use it with this data:

```py
movies = [
    {
        'title': 'kingsman',
        'speakers': ['JHON', 'KEVIN'],
        'dialogue': ['my name is jhon', 'hi..']
    }
]
```

The result would be:

```
      title speakers         dialogue
0  kingsman     JHON  my name is jhon
1  kingsman    KEVIN             hi..
```

It is slower than other solutions but more simple.

Comment: Why? Usually if performance matters it means that there are a lot of rows. And having a lot of rows I belive that what I said is true

Comment: I was doing exactly the same test and you are correct. Thank you.